# ios - view is not rendered until button is clicked

Tags: ios

I am developing a small ios app and I am struggling with a strange problem.
I have a view, in the view I have a button and a few images.
The images are loaded in an asynchronous manner. 
The view is hidden and is not initially part of the ViewController.

When a user clicks a button, I instantiate the view and add it as a subview.
When the subview is added, only some of the images are rendered (usually the first two, out of 25). When I click any button on the view though, all of a sudden all the other images appear.

What could cause this issue? Why do the images render only when I click a button? (the button has no code in its event handler).

Applying a timeout fixes this issue. I don't understand why though:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
}
```

I've tried supplying a code sample, but I can't seem to minimize it to a trivial example.

Comment: Sounds like you are not updating your UI and once you touch that button iOS automatically updates the UI showing your images. Remember that it can only be updated in the main thread.

Comment: why should I update my UI though? the images have already been loaded. Everything is done on the main thread

Comment: Are you sure the images finished loading before presenting your views?

Comment: do you sure that main thread was used to show(set) images?

Comment: I am calling performSelectorOnMainThread